# WebRTC streaming and CDN servers

Tags: webrtc, streaming, cdn

Im new to the world of streaming and just getting myself familiar with it,
I know basic WebRTC servers upto using Media servers such as Antmedia and Janus RTC.
Now I am doing research about CDN.

Can Web RTC be use with CDN servers? from my initial research, I can see that media servers such as AntMedia converts websockets to HLS before broadcasting it to CDNs.

However I can find articles that do claim they can do WebRTC and CDNs such as this:
https://flashphoner.com/dynamic-cdn-for-low-latency-webrtc-streaming/

or the claim made by Red5Pro here (number 8)
https://www.red5pro.com/blog/8-cdn-video-streaming-server-solutions-do-they-work/

Since traditional CDNs works by caching HTTP and only works in HTTP, I assume what these two are claiming are non traditional CDNs but instead they implemented their own "CDN" to relay/route video streams instead like another WebRTC gateways that do the relay.

what do you guys think?

Comment: Depends on how you define the capabilities of a "CDN" and what you want to accomplish. Turning a WebRTC stream into some CDN-compatible format and *broadcasting* it makes a lot of sense. Trying to do this with a bidirectional stream, i.e. a video *conversation*, probably makes less sense due to the delay which will almost inevitably be added by the necessary processing.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, yes our requirement is bidrectional stream, some sort of a game or something that has live video stream, so by what you said, CDN does not make sense this way. I have  a question though, by definition, using CDN is only one direction right? because of the origin-edge-client design thing, so if its a bidirection, that means the client also broadcast stuff as well, cant imagine how that works.

Comment: @curiousJorgeXX what was the result of your research? I would love to know, I am in the same position right now, we need to find out how to support 1000s of viewers across the world via WebRTC and is it good to use a CDN while avoiding latency. Thanks